# Lua script failed clicking on a button

Tags: web-scraping, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to scrape flights from [link](http://www.iaa.gov.il/en-us/airports/BenGurion/Pages/OnlineFlights.aspx) with scrapy-splash using this lua script:

```
function main(splash)
                local waiting_time = 2 

                -- Go to the URL
                assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
                splash:wait(waiting_time)

                -- Click on "Outgoing tab"
                local outgoing_tab = splash:select('#linkRealTimeOutgoing')
                outgoing_tab:mouse_click()
                splash:wait(waiting_time)

                -- Click on "More Flights" button
                local more_flights_btn = splash:select('#ctl00_rptOutgoingFlights_ctl26_divPaging > div.advanced.noTop > a')
                more_flights_btn:mouse_click()
                splash:wait(waiting_time)

                return splash:html()
end
```

and from some reason I'm getting this error:

```
'LUA_ERROR', 'message': 'Lua error: [string "..."]:16: attempt to index local \'more_flights_btn\' (a nil value)', 'error': "attempt to index local 'more_flights_btn' (a nil value)"}, 'type': 'ScriptError', 'description': 'Error happened while executing Lua script'}
```

Does anyone know why this happens?
Also does anyone know where I can get a toturial for lua script integration with splash? besides the offical site?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `splash:select('#ctl00_rpt...` returned `nil` instead of expected button object.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thank you for your answer! I checked on chrome using jQuery like: $('#ctl00_rptOutgoingFlights_ctl26_divPaging > div.advanced.noTop > a').click()
 and it's worked. any idea why lua script can't find the element?

Answer (score 1):

This just looks like a timing issue. I ran your Lua script a couple of times and I got that error only once.

Simply waiting longer before getting the button should be enough. However, if the time it takes varies a lot and you don't always want to wait the full time, then you can try a slightly smarter loop like this:

```
-- Click on "More Flights" button
local more_flights_btn
-- Wait up to 10 seconds:
for i=1,10 do
    splash:wait(1)
    more_flights_btn = splash:select('#ctl00_rptOutgoingFlights_ctl26_divPaging > div.advanced.noTop > a')
    if more_flights_btn then break end
    -- If it was not found we'll wait again.
end
```

Comment: I changed to your code, and still getting this error for nil element, I also tried while loop with condition (element == nil) and it doesn't help. any ideas? maybe something here is Async and need to make it sync?

Thanks